Bathroom light wiring
Trying to install new bathroom light and exhaust fan.  House wires have two black and two white copper lines with a red line and ground.  New light fan kit has two white, one blue and one black line that are aluminum.  Question is,  what do I do with the extra black copper line from the house

The new wires are probably (hopefully!) tinned copper and not aluminum. Model # of fan/light? Did you have a light, fan or both before? How many switches do you have?

Pictures of the old wiring (preferably before you detach the old fixture from the wiring) and the new fixture would be helpful.

Fixture wiring doesn't come in aluminum -- if you see silvery wires coming off fixtures, they're 100% tinned copper
